# How to get correct IPv6 Ip address?

Tags: android, networking, ipv6

I am trying to display the ip address of connected networks in android. I am using the following code. But it returns 2 IPv6 ip address. How to find the correct ip address from that?

I am using the following code:

```
List<LinkAddress> linkAddresses = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getLinkAddresses();
        for (LinkAddress linkAddress : linkAddresses) {
            Log.i("","LinkAddress getAddress "+linkAddress.getAddress() + "");
            Log.i("","Is IPV6 " + (linkAddress.getAddress() instanceof Inet6Address) +"");
            Log.i("","Is IPV4 " + (linkAddress.getAddress() instanceof Inet4Address) +"");
            Log.i("","Is isLinkLocalAddress " + (linkAddress.getAddress().isLinkLocalAddress()) +"");
            Log.i("","Is not isLoopbackAddress " + (!linkAddress.getAddress().isLoopbackAddress()) +"");
        }
```

Now I am getting 4 ip addresses.

```
LinkAddress getAddress /fe80::2d0:caff:fe00:5ad6
LinkAddress getAddress /2401:4900:2305:14e:2d0:caff:fe00:5ad6
LinkAddress getAddress /2401:4900:2305:14e:28e2:5192:e38f:3e9
LinkAddress getAddress /192.168.43.176
```

I can identify fe80 is Link Local Ip address and 192. is IPv4 address. But I am confused to identify IPV6 address from this. Please help me to find out the IPv6 ip address.

Comment: There are three IPv6 addresses there, not two. All three are correct. Which one to use depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Both IPv6 addresses are valid. It's normal to have multiple addresses per interface. Both are in the same subnet (2401:4900:2305:14e::/64). When you look at the interface ID (the second half of the address) you'll see that one has ..ff:fe.. in the middle. That's a sign that that address is probably derived from the MAC address of the interface. The other address is a temporary address that will change over time to protect the privacy of the user.

But in short: both addresses are completely valid and usable.